# Cotangent sheaf of a blow up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

It's well known that for a nonsingular variety $X$ and a nonsingular subvariety $Y$ with $\text{codim}(Y,X) \ge 2$, we can compute the canonical sheaf of $\widetilde{X}$ (the blow up of $X$ along $Y$) as the pullback of $\omega_{X}$ tensored with a power of the invertible sheaf associated to the preimage of $Y$ under the blowup map.

My question is the following: Are there situations where $\Omega^{1}_{\widetilde{X}}$ can be related to the pullback of $\Omega^{1}_{X}$ via a similar isomorphism, and if not, why?

Comment: There is always a simple relation: if $f:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X $ is the blowing up morphism and $i:E\hookrightarrow \widetilde{X}$ the embedding of the exceptional divisor, there is an exact sequence $
0 \to f^*\Omega_X \to \Omega_{\widetilde X} \to i_*\Omega_{E/Y} \to 0$.